# Unable to find xpath returning null HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, vb.net, xpath, nodes

This is where the error is (line below)

```
    Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//*[@id'requestKey']"))

    'if the div is found, print the inner text'
    If Not div Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox(div.GetAttributeValue("value", "nu"))

    End If

End Function
```

ALWAYS returns a null value.

This is the site
https://www.footlocker.com/product/model:272681/sku:CP8683/adidas-originals-tubular-shadow-knit-mens/black/grey/

I am using HTMLagilitypack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with quotes and double quotes in strings.
Your xpath is invalid, it should be something like:

```
//*[@id='requestKey']
```

or

```
//*[contains(@id, 'requestKey')]
```